# A word for something that is pleasant because it is intellectual challenging

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking specifically for an adjective. Let X denote that adjective. Here's an example for what I mean.

> He's not doing cancer research because he wants to improve and save the life of his patients, but because it is X.

Comment: you could use '*intellectually stimulating*', but that's not a single word... would '*fulfilling*' work?

Comment: Perhaps *gratifying*?

Comment: This might be a good candidate for a new spin on ***[Holmesian](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/holmesian),*** as the detective (at least in the recent BBC program) solves crimes not to save people, or to punish people, but for the intellectual challenge.